# Ruby will not return hash from function

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I have the following code:

```
def parse_package_url package, directory
  branchget = package.split '@'
  branch = branchget.length > 1 ? branchget[1] : false
  siteget = branchget[0].split(':')
  site = siteget.length > 1 ? siteget[0] : 'gitlab'
  repoget = (siteget.length > 1 ? siteget[1] : siteget[0]).split '/'
  packagename = repoget[1]
  packageuser = repoget[0]
  path = "#{directory}/#{packagename}"
  {
    :branch => branch,
    :site => site,
    :name => packagename,
    :user => packageuser
    :path => path,
    :repo => repoget.join('/')
  }
end
```

Upon running this code, I get the following errors:

```
syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting '}' (SyntaxError)
    :path => path,
     ^
syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
    :repo => repoget.join('/')
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
```

I cannot spot my syntax mistake in this code, and would appreciate if somebody could point it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the comma after `:user => packageuser` which is causing a syntax error. With errors like these, years of staring have taught me the issue is often with one line above the line number Ruby gives you.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still getting an `unexpected $end` but I suspect it's coming from a different syntax mistake instead. The weirdest part is that it found this same code perfectly acceptable just yesterday...